# How to do this in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am using [Stupid Fixed Header](http://jackysee.googlepages.com/fixedheaders.html) to fix the headers of two tables. For that i am using following script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    $("#table1").fixedHeader({
        height: 160,
        adjustWidth: function(th){
        if($.browser.msie){
            return $(th).width()+10;
        }
            return $(th).width();
        }
    });

    $("#table2").fixedHeader({
        height: 160,
        adjustWidth: function(th){
        if($.browser.msie){
            return $(th).width()+10;
        }
            return $(th).width();
        }
    });
})
```

Now the point is, i am writing the same code twice. Once for table1 and then for table2. Is it possible to write it only once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("#table1, #table2").fixedHeader ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a class selector instead of id selector. Something like

```
$(".tablefidedheaders").fixedHeader({
        height: 160,
        adjustWidth: function(th){
        if($.browser.msie){
                return $(th).width()+10;
        }
                return $(th).width();
        }
    });
```

Give the class name [tablefidedheaders] for the two tables.

Answer (score 1):

As adamantium said, selecting by class is probably a better practice. If you want to select by multiple ids, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){           
    $("#table1, #table2").fixedHeader({
        height: 160,
        adjustWidth: function(th){
        if($.browser.msie){
                return $(th).width()+10;
        }
                return $(th).width();
        }
    });
```